# Unable to get the environment variable using PHP hosted in amazon linux

Tags: php, apache, environment-variables, amazon-linux

I set up the environment path in amazon linux vi /etc/environment as ENV_TYPE=DEV.  Environment variable are set up in localhost but it not get the environment in web host.

In apache path /var/www/html I create a index.php with below code:

```
<?php
 echo "env ".getenv('ENV_TYPE');
 exit;
?>
```

I already tried the below commands for setup,

```
vi etc/environment --> ENV_TYPE=DEV
```

[image]

OUTPUT from my host is " **env **" only but expected Output is "**env DEV**"
the issue is env only execute in this code , ENV_TYPE not fetched from environment variable!!!

output image [image]

i expected output image is [image]

Answer (score 0):

set the Local environment in the path file **/etc/environmet**

```
export ENV_TYPE=DEV
```

then, save and Create a **.htaccess** file in the apache path **/var/www/html** and add the line in .htaccess file.

```
SetEnv ENV_TYPE "DEV"
```

Allow the .ht file permission in apache conf (httpd.conf) file

Finally, it's automatically taken the Environment Variable as **Dev**